# How do I make Branch ID dependent on the selected Branch?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I'm trying to create a custom primary key that's incrementing and dependent on the branch that was inputted. For example, if I input 'MIAMI' as the branch, the ID will display as MI0001, and if I input 'CALIFORNIA', it will display CA0001 and so on. How do I do it? Here's what I've got so far.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.tblCompany
  (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   CompanyID AS 'MI-' + RIGHT('00000000' + CAST(ID AS VARCHAR(3)), 3) PERSISTED,
   FirstName VARCHAR(30),
   LastName VARCHAR(30),
   Branch VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
   CHECK(Branch IN('MIAMI', 'CALIFORNIA', 'NEW YORK', 'SEATTLE'))
  )
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using MySQL? `dbo` is usually with SQL-Server.

Comment: MySQL doesn't have `IDENTITY()`.

Answer (score 1):

You would have to use an INSTEAD OF INSERT trigger, and scan the target table or maintain separate SEQUECE objects for each branch.

So it's not worth doing and you shouldn't try.

Comment: Could you walk me through it please? i'm just starting SQL server and it's for a school project

Comment: Nope.  You should just use an IDENTITY or SEQUENCE.